# How to send SNI with Jsoup?

Tags: java, ssl, jsoup, tls1.2, jsse

I'm using Jsoup to connect to a website supporting TLSv1.2. The server supports Server Name Indication extension (SNI) and I would like to send this as a parameter from my client.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: Jsoup uses `HttpsURLConnection` which in **java 7 or 8 sends SNI automatically**. Note SNI is not related to protocol version and works fine on TLSv1, 1.1 or 1.2. However, if the server *requires* 1.2 and you are still(!) using java 7, that doesn't *enable* 1.2 by default; set system property `https.protocols`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. When I perform the client request, wireshark shows that SNI is not included with ClientHello whereas it is with requests in a browser. This is despite using Java 8. Any ideas?

Comment: Try a program that does `(new URL ("htpps://whatever")).openConnection().connect()`. If that doesn't send SNI, identify your exact JRE (update, Oracle vs OpenJDK, any patches etc). If it does but your Jsoup doesn't, make the smallest example you can that has the problem and post it (edit your question).